# Outline text with System.Drawing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, graphics, system.drawing

I have the following code.  Is there an easy way to put an outline on the text I am writing?

```
 var imageEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
 var imageEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
 imageEncoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(imageEncoder, 100L);

 var productImage = GetImageFromByteArray(myViewModel.ProductImage.DatabaseFile.FileContents);
 var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(productImage);

 var font = new Font("Segoe Script", 24);
 var brush = Brushes.Orange;

 var container = new Rectangle(myViewModel.ContainerX, myViewModel.ContainerY,                                      myViewModel.ContainerWidth,                                              myViewModel.ContainerHeight);

 var stringFormat = new StringFormat {Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center};

 graphics.DrawString(customizationText, font, brush, container, stringFormat);
```

Comment: I find your lack of "using" disturbing.

Answer (score 45):

Yes. Instead of DrawString, use the following sequence of calls:

- [`new GraphicsPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.aspx) (creates an empty `GraphicsPath`)
- [`GraphicsPath.AddString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.addstring.aspx) (the `GraphicsPath` object now represents the outline of the text)
- [`Graphics.DrawPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawpath.aspx) (draws the outline in any `Pen` you want)

If you need to use `GraphicsPath.AddString` alongside `Graphics.DrawString`, you need to convert the font sizes, because `Graphics.DrawString` expects “point size” while `GraphicsPath.AddString` expects “em size”. The conversion formula is simply `emSize = g.DpiY * pointSize / 72`.

Here's a code example:

```
// assuming g is the Graphics object on which you want to draw the text
GraphicsPath p = new GraphicsPath(); 
p.AddString(
    "My Text String",             // text to draw
    FontFamily.GenericSansSerif,  // or any other font family
    (int) FontStyle.Regular,      // font style (bold, italic, etc.)
    g.DpiY * fontSize / 72,       // em size
    new Point(0, 0),              // location where to draw text
    new StringFormat());          // set options here (e.g. center alignment)
g.DrawPath(Pens.Black, p);
// + g.FillPath if you want it filled as well
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, but I can't seem to get this to work.  I am not sure which overload(s) to use for these methods.  Would the only line I take out of my current program be the graphics.DrawString() line?

Comment: Thanks for this info, I did just what you said...

But of course I realized that there's no anti-aliasing so text looks pretty awful. :(  Not sure what to do about that yet.

Comment: @QuinxyvonBesiex: I always set `g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;`, `g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;`, `g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;` and `g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;`. One of these controls the anti-aliasing for lines and shapes.

Comment: @Timwi, thanks! I ended up doing something along the lines of what you said, but the super-critical part I was not understanding was that I was creating the text on a graphics object that already had the image over which the text was supposed to go, so I think that was most of my problem.  I then modified my code to use a separate Image/Graphics context and then copy the text back onto the image once it was rendered.  Now everything works well!  Thanks again.