# ASCII characters to polygon

Tags: ascii, polygon

We need to have ASCII set equivalent to Polygon shapes. Is there a script or routine available? request part with or provide some solution. This is required to print the text annotation on plotter which does not understand plain text.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please look up what's [allowed & on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site as well as [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Asking for outside scripts is off topic and not allowed.  Additionally, asking for someone to do something for you will usually end up with getting your question downvoted.  SO is for providing help to specific questions about programming, not for requesting development of a solution.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your platform.

On Windows with .Net you can convert a string with a TTF font into a GraphicsPath object. Then you can convert the GraphicsPath into a sequence of points to send to your plotter.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142533(v=vs.110).aspx

See also `GetGlyphOutline`

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144891(v=vs.85).aspx

I am certain that other platforms and libraries have similar capabilities.

Related:

- [Outline of a text as single line vector path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797787/outline-of-a-text-as-single-line-vector-path)